# Question on offsetting when resampling a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to resample a dataset for every 3 hours with a 1 hour offset. When I attempt it, the time is offset by 1 hour and set for every 3 hours as desired, but the values are only resampled and not taking into account the offset

My attempt has looked like this

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Raw Data.xlsx')
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].astype(float) * 1000
hourly = df.resample('H', on='TIME').mean()
thirdly = df.resample('3H', loffset = '1H', on='TIME').mean()
```

as shown, I've been able to make an hourly set, but when I try to create the 3 hour resample with the offset, I get this as my result

```py
                    DATA
TIME    
2019-07-29 22:00:00 10.777778
2019-07-30 01:00:00 14.055556
2019-07-30 04:00:00 13.333333
2019-07-30 07:00:00 8.722222
2019-07-30 10:00:00 7.333333
...
```

when my raw data looks like this

```py
TIME    DATA
0   2019-07-29 22:33:34 11.0
1   2019-07-29 22:43:34 10.0
2   2019-07-29 22:53:34 10.0
3   2019-07-29 23:03:34 10.0
4   2019-07-29 23:13:34 10.0
5   2019-07-29 23:23:34 11.0
6   2019-07-29 23:33:34 11.0
7   2019-07-29 23:43:34 12.0
8   2019-07-29 23:53:34 12.0
9   2019-07-30 00:03:34 11.0
10  2019-07-30 00:13:34 12.0
11  2019-07-30 00:23:34 13.0
12  2019-07-30 00:33:34 13.0
13  2019-07-30 00:43:34 14.0
14  2019-07-30 00:53:34 14.0
...
```

When you calculate it by hand, you can see that the average it is taking is actually from 21:00-24:00 instead of the 22:00-1:00 as it shows despite me offsetting in the resample. How do I correct this?

Comment: Does adding this change anything? 
`thirdly = df.resample('3H', loffset = '1H', closed = 'right', on ='TIME').mean()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameter `base` instead of `loffset` which only adjust the labels.

Try:

```
thirdly = df.resample('3H', base = 1, on='TIME').mean()
```